# Call to a member function getResultArray() on bool codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter

I am gettin this error
Call to a member function getResultArray() on bool

in my pc run very good but in my hosting i have this error

What can I do? help me please

```
'public function obt_lista_prestamos($activo)
{    
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$db = db_connect();
$builder = $db->table('t_prestamo');
$builder->select('*');
$builder->join('t_clientes', 't_prestamo.fk_idcliente = t_clientes.id_cliente');
$query = $builder->get();    
$query = $query->getResultArray();    
return ($query);
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems fine, but you can try with this:

```
'public function obt_lista_prestamos($activo)
 {    
 $db = \Config\Database::connect();
 $db = db_connect();
 $builder = $db->table('t_prestamo');
 $builder->select('*');
 $builder->join('t_clientes', 't_prestamo.fk_idcliente =                
 t_clientes.id_cliente');
 $query = $builder->get()->getResultArray();    
 return ($query);
}'
```

I had the same problem and this worked for me.
Note this line: $query = $builder->get()->getResultArray();